# Is there a way to run a persistent Docker container, like a VPS?

Tags: docker, containers

Problem: I have a NAS machine at home, built out of old hardware. Virtualization does not work on it due to bug in motherboard. Docker, however, runs perfectly. I want to have a single small VPS on that machine.

Question: Is there a way to run a Docker container in such a way, that I could SSH into it, make changes, install packages and it will be persistent across reboots? I don't need neither speed no enterprise reliability, just a hack. I would use it for simple tasks like "unpack archives" or "monitor for proper  file permissions on the share" and I don't feel like writing docker files every time I want to run anything. If I caould not make it work, I'll buy a RapberryPi to plug alongside the NAS.

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of containers,

1) Application containers - should run an instance of an application per container, (including any dependencies of course).

2) System containers - can run multiple applications like a normal virtual machine.

[Docker's primary use-case](https://docs.docker.com/engine/docker-overview/#what-can-i-use-docker-for) is for running applications in containers. Whereas, [LXC](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/introduction/#features) or OpenVZ are used for the later.

If you would like to run a specific application in a Docker container, you can use an orchestration tool like [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/#single-host-deployments), or [kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io) to manage your container.

However, if you are just trying to use a container like a virtual machine, you would just set it up like regular. The only difference is, you would run the LXC or OpenVZ container as a service just like normal.

I think the latter option suits your use-case more than the Docker option.

Comment: I should have clarified: I am stuck with Docker there. It is a specialized distro Unraid without any extraneous files, including package manager. If I could have run chroot on it, I would not be asking this.

Comment: Oh I see. I would create a Docker image that contains `OpenSSH`, and some of the other tools you'll likely use. Then for your `CMD`, I would write a simple shell script that launches those services. Docker containers aren't really meant to run a full init system, so this is a bit of a workaround. Also, when you launch your container, you should use a `VOLUME` so that your changes are saved to disk.